# Error while evaluating property 'compilerOptions.jvmTarget

Tags: ios

```
            REPO_ROOT="$PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT"
            "$REPO_ROOT/../../gradlew" -p "$REPO_ROOT" $KOTLIN_PROJECT_PATH:syncFramework                     -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.platform=$PLATFORM_NAME                     -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.archs="$ARCHS"                     -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.configuration="$CONFIGURATION"
```

> Task :buildSrc:buildSrc:compileKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:buildSrc:compileKotlin'.

> Error while evaluating property 'compilerOptions.jvmTarget' of task ':buildSrc:buildSrc:compileKotlin'.
> Failed to calculate the value of property 'jvmTarget'.
> > Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 20

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

I myself just did not understand what the problem is, but I use JVM target: 11

Comment: have you found a solution for this ?